# Why does this series expansion for $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ fail using $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to do (2nd order) Taylor expansion for 
$$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$ using $$\frac{1}{1-x}$$

What I do is write

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot, \text{ at } x_0=0$$

and

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

so

$$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{1-(1-\cos(x))}=1+(1-\cos(x))+(1-\cos(x))^2$$
$$=1+(1-1+\frac{x^2}{2!})+(1-1+\frac{x^2}{2!})^2$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^4$$

[which is correct up to order 2](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/maclaurin-series-calculator/maclaurin%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bcos%5Cleft%28x%5Cright%29%7D) ([or order 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930290/on-the-order-indexing-of-different-taylor-series)), but the coefficient of $x^4$ (is that 3rd or 4th order?) is wrong.

Why? How can I get the correct coefficients for higher orders?

And if I do want only 2nd order Taylor polynomial, then what is the term $\frac{1}{4}x^4$?

Comment: @Mattos Because I'm calculating only the 2nd order? Or maybe I'm truncating the series wrongly?

Comment: I should probably go to bed. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you make things more complex than what they are?

If you want the expansion of this function, say up to order $6$, simply write $\;\dfrac1{\cos x}=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^4}{24}-\dfrac{x^6}{720}+o(x^7)}$, for instance, and set
$$u=\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{x^4}{24}+\dfrac{x^6}{720}+o(x^7)$$
Now do the calculations for $\dfrac1{1-u}$ up to order $3$ (since the polynomial part of $u$ has order $2$), truncating the results for each power at order $6$:
\begin{alignat}{5}
1+u&=1+\frac{x^2}2&&-\frac{x^4}{24}&&+\frac{x^6}{720}&&+o(x^7)\\
{}+u^2&=&&+\frac{x^4}{4}&&-\frac{x^6}{24}&&+o(x^7)\\
{}+u^3&=&&&&+\frac{x^6}{8}&&+o(x^7)\\
\hline
\frac1{\cos x}&=1+\frac{x^2}2&&+\frac{5x^4}{24}&&+\frac{59x^6}{24}&&+o(x^7)
\end{alignat}

*Alternatively*, you can divide $1$ by $1-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^4}{24}-\dfrac{x^6}{720}$ by *increasing powers* (not the Euclidean division!) up to degree $6$.

Comment: Can you clarify how the division (last part) works?

Comment: You can see an explicit example in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893913/by-using-a-geometric-series-and-a-factorisation-compute-the-first-three-terms-o/1893977#1893977).Please let me know if it is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You did not calculate the 3rd and 4th order coefficients like this, only the second (you have some $o(x^2)$ remaining from the first term, of which the $\frac{x^4}{4}$ is a part of).

In order to get the fourth (the third is null by parity), you need all terms that will give a fourth order coefficient, so that you are only left with some $o(x^4)$

In your case, for the fourth coefficient, it would be

$\frac{1}{cos(x)} =  1 + (1-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} + o(x^4))+(1-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} + o(x^4))^2$

$= 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^4}{4} + o(x^4) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{5x^4}{24} + o(x^4)$

Comment: So in my calculations for 2nd order Taylor polynomial what is the $\frac{1}{4}x^4$ term then?

Comment: you are left with $o(x^2) + \frac{x^4}{4}$, this is not more than some $o(x^2)$. When calculating a second order, there is no fourth order term

Comment: What do you mean "when calculating a second order"? Haven't I calculated the second order?

Comment: Yes you did, but you certainly did not calculate the fourth order, which is why your fourth order coefficient is wrong. It is no suprise to have a wrong fourth order coefficient when you calculate the second, since you just want something ending with $o(x^2)$

Comment: But why am I getting an extra term? What's that extra term?

Comment: Part of some function $f$ verifying $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 0$. When you calculate the $n$th order, DO NOT take into account ANY term with a power of $x$ which is $>n$, since the are part of the $o(x^n)$

Comment: Okay so to get 2nd order it would be much clearer to write the expansion first as infinite or nth order and then just truncate it to desired order by using little o notation for the extra terms?