# Infinite series from Euler

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am reading Euler's Introduction to analysis of the infinite" and is stumped at this section:

[image]

How does he derive the part that I circled in red?

I thought:

$\dfrac{a+bz+cz^2+...}{z(1-\alpha\cdot z-\beta\cdot z^2...)}=A+Bz+Cz^2+Dz^3+Ez^4...$

is gonna be:

$a+bz+cz^2+...=z(1-\alpha\cdot z-\beta\cdot z^2...)(A+Bz+Cz^2+Dz^3+Ez^4...)$

$=(z-\alpha\cdot z^2-\beta\cdot z^3...)(A+Bz+Cz^2+Dz^3+Ez^4)=(Az-\alpha\cdot Az^2-\beta\cdot Az^3...)+(Bz^2-\alpha\cdot B\cdot z^3-\beta\cdot B\cdot z^4...)$

So how does he have a fraction there, I don't understand.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Equate constant terms ($z^0$ terms )
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+bz+cz^2+\cdots= (Az-\alpha\cdot Az^2-\beta\cdot Az^3 \cdots)+(Bz^2-\alpha\cdot B\cdot z^3-\beta\cdot B\cdot z^4 \cdots)
\end{eqnarray*}
would give $a=0$ ... $\ddot \frown$

Comment: You are right, there is something wrong with my calculation, I still don't realize where it is wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

What you thought is impossible: the fraction has $0$ as a pole, and your r.h.s. has none. What our friend Leonard does is expanding first $\;\dfrac{a+b+cz^2+...}{1-\alpha\cdot z-\beta\cdot z^2 -\dotsb}$ via the standard formula for the geometric series, then multiplies the result by $\dfrac 1z$ (or $\dfrac1{z^m}$).

This way, he obtains an expansion of the function as what is known a *Laurent series*, since the function (and the series) has poles.

Comment: Can you do this in a few more steps so I can learn. What's wrong with my derivation? I just cross-multiply them, is this wrong? What is a pole? I haven't studied complex analysis so this concept is still foreign to me. How do you expand the left hand side using geometric series formula?

Comment: A pole is a root of the denominator. In your derivation, there is no denominator, hence no pole. For the expansion with the geometric series, one can substitute to the variable $x$ a series which is $0$ when $x=0$. In practice one performs a division by *increasing powers* of the truncated series (which are polynomials) up  to a certain order chosen in advance.

Comment: so how do you expand the fraction into geometric series, can you do this in a few more steps. I still don't understand how Euler derive the expression that I circle in red.

Comment: For Euler's derivation I explained he first expands the fraction  without the factor $z$ in the denominator, then divides the result by $z$ to recover the initial function. For the expansion using division by increasing powers there is an example in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893913/by-using-a-geometric-series-and-a-factorisation-compute-the-first-three-terms-o/1893977#1893977).

Answer (score 0):

You are happy with geometrically expanding ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1- \alpha z - \beta z^2  -\cdots} &=& 1+(\alpha z + \beta z^2  -\cdots)+( \alpha z + \beta z^2  +\cdots)^2+ \cdots \\
&=& 1+pz+qz^2+ \cdots. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let multiply in the numerator
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a+bz+cz^2+\cdots }{1- \alpha z - \beta z^2  -\cdots} &=& (a+bz+cz^2+\cdots)( 1+pz+qz^2+ \cdots)  \\
&=& A+Bz+Cz^2 + \cdots.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now if we divide by $z$, we get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a+bz+cz^2+\cdots }{z(1- \alpha z - \beta z^2  -\cdots)} &=&&=& \frac{A}{z}+B+Cz + \cdots.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
As required ?

Comment: I think I know the series expansion for $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, so you replace $x$ by the part $(\alpha \cdot z-\beta \cdot z^2...)$. I see now. So this is called geometric series expansion?

Comment: Yeah ... that's right .. + beta (not minus).